# oracle 10g, select clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

suppose a table employees with 14 rows and i want to select only middle rows like from 3 to 10 then how it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

First you'll have to define an ordering. Without an ordering, "middle rows like from 3 to 10" is meaningless. When you know the ordering, you can use almost the same query as RC proposed:

```
select *
  from ( select e.*
              , rownum rn
           from emp e
          order by <your ordering columns here>
       )
 where rn between 3 and 10
```

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT e.*, rownum r FROM emp e) WHERE r BETWEEN 3 AND 10;
```

Comment: This produces an undeterministic result.

Comment: Yes, this does provide an undeterministic result, but what the question is asking is for an undeterministic answer in most cases.  There are situations where this would be deterministic such as when the table is index organized and stored sorted by the primary key.

Comment: -1 by "undeterministic" RW meant "unreliable, not guaranteed, not useful" - if you don't have an ORDER BY, the results are never guaranteed to be in order.

Comment: @Jeffrey - I understand what undeterministic means and to say results are never guaranteed to be in order is incorrect.  There is no guarantee for heap tables, but for index organized tables (or clustered tables in other RDBMSs) the rows are stored in order based on the primary key.  I'm not saying that providing an explicit order isn't "better", but that order was not specified in the question.  The OP asked "how do I get rows 3-10 of a table", and that is what my solution provides.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's an index organized table, you can't write code that depends on it - just asking for trouble. To be correct, your solution *requires* that the table have a particular structure, but you never specified that; but even then, there's nothing stopping the DBA from rebuilding the table as a heap table, thus making your code simply wrong.

Comment: Bottom line: there is no good reason to omit the ORDER BY clause in a query that needs it, like this one. The OP asked "how do I get rows 3-10 of a table", and this logically assumes an ordering of some sort. Any other interpretation is meaningless.

Comment: @Jeffrey - I agree with you on all points if the question stated what he was interested in sorting on or what column he was basing the results on. He doesn't.  He asks for 3-10 records of a table.  We don't know based on his question why he wants this and maybe he likes the fact that it's indeterminent.  You're also correct that getting 3-10 rows of the table does logically assume ordering, but that ordering could in fact be the order they physically exist in the table.  Just because it's indeterminent doesn't make it "meaningless".

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a random sampling of rows, you can use the sample clause.  It is based on percentages, however.

select * from table sample (5);
-- 5 percent

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to get "all rows except for the top 3 and the bottom 3", regardless of the number of rows in the table, you could use this:

```
select * from (
  select emp.*,
         row_number() over (order by id) n,
         count(*) over () c
  from emp)
where n between 4 and c - 4;
```

If your requirement is to get "all the rows except for the top 20% and the bottom 20%", you could use this:

```
select * from (
  select emp.*,
         ntile(5) over (order by id) n,
         count(*) over () c
  from emp)
where n between 2 and 4;
```